# sendSignedTransaction - (node:90923) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: Invalid Signature

Tags: web3js, nodejs, ganache

Hi I'm using `Web3js` and `Ganache`. I'm trying  to send a serialized transaction but got the following error:
`(node:90923) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: Invalid Signature` . I've tried to switch *Node* version from *14.x.x* to *12.x.x* but no success. Not sure if the issue comes from `Web3js` or from `@ethereumjs/tx`...

Any ideas? Anyone experienced the same issue?

Thanks!

```
const EthereumTx  = require("@ethereumjs/tx").Transaction;

const URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:7545';

const web3 = new Web3(URL);

const sendingAddress = '0xEF72345AD7616204dfD98D61716ba3222eb085eC';
const receivingAddress = '0x286164093efbaea6143F62212aA37A56Cd85362c';

web3.eth.getBalance(sendingAddress).then(console.log);
web3.eth.getBalance(receivingAddress).then(console.log);

// *********CREATE A TRANSACTION*********

const rawTransaction = {
    nonce: 0,
    to: receivingAddress,
    gasPrice: 20000000,
    gasLimit: 30000,
    value: 100,
    data: ""
};

// -- Step 7: Sign the transaction with the Hex value of the private key of the sender

const privateKeySender = 'PRIVATE KEY';
const privateKeySenderHex = new Buffer.from(privateKeySender, 'hex');
const transaction = new EthereumTx(rawTransaction);
// console.log('transaction', transaction);
transaction.sign(privateKeySenderHex)

// // -- Step 8: Send the serialized signed transaction to the Ethereum network.

const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize();
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex'));
```

Comment: Did you try to replace 'PRIVATE KEY' with the private key provided by Ganache?

Comment: Hi @IsmailElMoudni yes of course :) the problem most likely happens in `sendSignedTransaction` method

Answer (score 0):

transaction.sign(privateKeySenderHex) return new object
try:

```
const signedTx = transaction.sign(privateKeySenderHex);
const serializedTransaction = signedTx.serialize();
```

full example:

```
singTransaction({ privateKey, to, value }: ArgsSingTransaction) {
 const hexPrivatekey = Buffer.from(privateKey, 'hex');

 const gasPrice = 20000000000;
 const gasLimit = 6721975;
 const nonce = 0;

 const tx = new Tx({ to: to, value: value, gasPrice, gasLimit, nonce, });

 const signedTx = tx.sign(hexPrivatekey);

 const serializedTx = signedTx.serialize();
 console.log(signedTx.isSigned())
 console.log(signedTx.validate())
 console.log(signedTx.verifySignature())
 console.log(signedTx.errorStr())

 return '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');
}
```